# Where can I find an implementation of C99's math for Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2005, c99

I have some code that uses several math functions that exist in C99, but aren't defined in math.h or cmath that come with VS2005. Anywhere I can get a VS2005 compatible implementation of C99?

Comment: +1. I'm searching for the same thing (now a year later...)

Answer (score 2):

VS doesn't support C99 at all :(  You could always nick it from BSD's libc in a pinch or from some other source (GCC probably has it, but might run into licensing issues)